# Impact of reencoding an HEVC file: How much loss if I do it in two steps, vs. going directly to a lower bitrate?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, bitrate, hevc

My scenario is as follows:

- Working with large original 8K file, captured at 100Mb/sec with hvec (h265) codec
- The file was reencoded at 50Mb/sec for a reasonable balance between size and quality

Now there's a requirement is to lower the bitrate for space savings, going to 40Mb/sec.

My questions are:

- Is there a benefit to go back to the original file and reencode it at 40Mb/sec bitrate, vs. using the already reduced 50Mb/sec file and reencoding that one at 40Mb/sec?
- If there's indeed such a benefit, can we quantify it in comparison to the intermediate bitrate version of the file?
- If there was a follow-up requirement to further reduce the bitrate to 30Mb/sec, what would be the benefit of going with the 40, 50, or the 100Mb/sec versions?

For reference, ffmpeg would be the encoding tool, using similar options to those listed below:

```
-c:v hevc_nvenc -preset p6 -tune hq -b:v 40M
```